# Не работает заполнение массива ГСЧ

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Есть очень интересная задача. Нужно заполнить двумерный массив MxN случайными числами в диапазоне [-5; 10] с помощью ГСЧ, а потом посчитать среднее арифметическое чисел, которые входят в диапазон [5; 15]. Не могу понять, почему не работает заполнение чисел. Также не могу понять, как проверять диапазон чисел, которые будут сгенерированы. Очень нужна помощь.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <time.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
    const int m1 = 5;
    const int n1 = 5;
    int f[m1][n1];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i3 = 0; i3 < 5; i3++){
        f[m1][n1] = -8 + rand() % 8;
        cout << f[i3] << " " << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: вам дали уже три ответа, может какой нибудь помог и надо поблагодарить людей за помощь????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама **программа**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int m1 = 5;
    const int n1 = 5;
    int f[m1][n1], count_of_numbers = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n1; ++j){
           f[i][j] =  -5 + rand() % 16;
           cout << f[i][j] << " ";
           if (f[i][j] >= 5 && f[i][j] <= 15){
               sum += f[i][j];
               ++count_of_numbers;
           }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << "\nFinal result = " << sum/count_of_numbers;
    system("pause");
}
```

1) Убираем библиотеку `math.h` - она не понадобиться.

2) В 9 строке вместе с объявлением массива *f*, объявляем переменную _count_of_numbers_ типа `int` для подсчёта количества элементов среднеарифметического чисел.

```
int f[m1][n1], count_of_numbers = 0;
```

3) В 10 строке объявляем переменную *sum* типа `float` для подсчёта суммы элементов среднеарифметического чисел.

```
float sum = 0;
```

4) Начиная с 11 строки начинается вложенный цикл, необходимый для инициализации элементов массива *f*.
Переменная *i* необходима для перехода по строкам двумерного массива, а переменная *j* для перехода по столбцам этого же массива.

5) Немного про `rand()`. Изначально функция `rand()` генерирует случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до 32767. После записи `rand()` *%* *n* минимальное возможное число это 0, максимальное *n*-1 (*%* это взятие остатка от деления, поэтому максимальное число это *n*-1). Финальный вариант для генерирования случайных строк выглядит так:

```
f[i][j] =  -5 + rand() % 16;
```

Минимальное число после `rand()` *%* 16 это 0, поэтому минимальное число после -5 + `rand()` *%* 16 это -5.
Максимальное число после `rand()` % 16 это 15, поэтому максимальное число после -5 + `rand()` *%* 16 это 10.

6) В 15 строке в поле `if` после присваивания элементу матрицы случайной величины происходит проверка на вхождение в заданный диапазон:

```
if (f[i][j] >= 5 && f[i][j] <= 15)
```

Если элемент массива `f[i][j]` не меньше 5 `f[i][j]` *>=* 5 и (*&&* - логическое и) элемент массива не больше 15 `f[i][j]` *<=* 15, то увеличивается сумма чисел подходящих под данное условие:

```
sum += f[i][j];
```

данное выражение можно **переписать**:

```
sum = sum + f[i][j];
```

и увеличивается кол-во таких чисел:

```
++count_of_numbers;
```

данное выражение также можно **переписать**:

```
count_of_numbers = count_of_numbers + 1;
```

7) в 22 строке происходит вывод среднеарифметического чисел.
Среднеарифметическое чисел **это сумма чисел делённое на их количество**, поэтому на вывод подаётся выражение:

```
cout << "\nFinal result = " << sum/count_of_numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Куда* вы пишете случайные числа?

```
 f[m1][n1] = -8 + rand() % 8;
```

Все время в одно и то же место, причем за пределами выделенного массива.

```
    cout << f[i3] << " " << endl;
```

А выводить пытаетесь просто адреса строк вашего массива...

Входит ли `n` в диапазон `[a,b]` проверяется просто -

```
if (n >= a && n <= b) ...
```

Comment: А почему int f[m1][n1] запрещено?

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup А потому что в C++ VLA нет, *размер массива должен быть известен во время компиляции*.

Comment: Так в его коде m1 и n1 обьявлены как const int.

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup Блин! тяжелый был денек, такой фигни к вечеру понаписал... Огромное спасибо, вы, конечно, правы... мне почему-то показалось, что он их читает...

Comment: Со всеми бывает. Главное, что человеку помогли.

Comment: @Harry где вы нашли тут случайные числа?

Comment: @Andrey Ну хорошо, псевдослучайные. Это что-то меняет?

Comment: @Harry даже не псеудо... просто результат x(t)

Answer (score 0):

Вы таки на `C++` пишите или на `C`? Если на `C++`, то распределение ваших чисел задаётся одной строчкой `std::uniform_int_distribution(5,15)`. Для заполнения тоже ровно 1 строчка `std::generate(matrix.begin(),matrix.end(),generator)`. Далее стандартный filter+fold, в рамках `C++` - `std::copy_if` + `std::accumulate`